# For loop in python / arcpy SQL expression invalid, selection not working

Tags: python, for-loop, arcgis, arcpy, cursors

I am creating a python script where I am trying to iterate over point feature class. I want to create seperate Feature classes from each individual day. So select daynumber and then export it to a new FC with an unique daynumber as name.

I was unable to find my answer online. So I decided to ask my question here.

ArcGIS 10.2

My script looks as follows:

```
test1 = "D:\\Mijn_Doc\\Test_Geodatabase.gd\\test1"
dayno = 2618
with test1 as rows:
    for row in rows:
        query = '"daynumber = '+ str(dayno) + '"'
        arcpy.Select_analysis(test1, 'D:\\Mijn_Doc\\Test_Geodatabase.gdb\\select'+str(dayno), query)
    dayno +=1
```

The error I get is:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "daynumber = 2618"
>   Failed to execute (Select)

the selection looks fine, If I build it in Model Builder and export it to a Python script the expression looks the same as it looks in this Error message.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you have two quotes there? perhaps simple `query='daynumber=%s' % dayno` would be enough?

Comment: `with test1 as rows:` makes no sense -- did you mean `with open(test1) as rows:`?

Answer (score 1):

Ashalynd, your advice was part of the solution, many thanks for that

This was the (working) script I was looking for:

```
dayno = 2618
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(test1, ('daynumber',)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        query= query='daynumber=%s' % dayno
        if dayno > 2630:
            break
        else:
            arcpy.Select_analysis(test1, selecttest + str(dayno), query)
            dayno +=
```